# Is it possible to create a Roslyn analyzer that requires any class that derives from a specific base class to include a static field

Tags: c#, roslyn

This is a stripped down version of the code I have now.

```
public abstract class Base
{

}

public interface IStringConstructable
{
    Base Construct(string s);
}

public interface IStreamConstructable
{
    Base Construct(Stream stream);
}

public class Derived1 : Base, IStreamConstructable
{
    private static Derived1 singleton = new Derived1();
    public static Derived1 Singleton { get { return singleton; } }

    private Derived1() { }
    public Derived1(Stream stream) { }

    Base IStreamConstructable.Construct(Stream stream)
    {
        return new Derived1(stream);
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Base, IStringConstructable, IStreamConstructable
{
    private static Derived2 singleton = new Derived2();
    public static Derived2 Singleton { get { return singleton; } }

    private Derived2() { }
    public Derived2(string s) { }
    public Derived2(Stream stream) { }

    Base IStringConstructable.Construct(string s)
    {
        return new Derived2(s);
    }

    Base IStreamConstructable.Construct(Stream stream)
    {
        return new Derived2(stream);
    }
}
```

The whole point of this is that I want to avoid using reflection wherever possible. And I want everything that is required in the implementation of the derived type to be a compile time requirement. I can get a list of the instances of each interface that is implemented for a given derived type. I can then call the correct Construct method depending on the scenario. Knowing whether or not the Singleton field/property is present is the problem. There is no guarantee that this property will exist on every derived class because this propery is not required on the Base class. And this property should not be required for every derived class. Only the ones that implment one of the interfaces. Without the interfaces, there is no guarantee that a matching constructor will exist.

This all leads me to my question of whether or not it is possible to create a Roslyn analyzer that can check if a specific class contains a specific property/field. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Before you get into writing a Roslyn analyzer to enforce a pattern, maybe you should rethink the pattern. "Singleton" doesn't just mean "statically stored instance"; it means *single* instance, as in the only one ever. These are not singletons. You have kind of a mix of the Prototype pattern (without basing instances on the prototype instance) and some sort of factory. You probably should go with full-fledged factories (separate types) and require that you inject the factories for the things you need to construct where you need them.

Comment: Singleton is probably a bad name then. It was merely a way to access an instance method outlined by the interface statically.

Comment: Regardless of the name, the whole pattern is bizarre. Every object that follows this pattern also can be a factory for others of its kind. That's fine if you're trying to model parthenogenesis, for example, but I'm guessing you're not.

Comment: In fact, I dub this the "Parthenogenesis Pattern". You heard it here first.

Comment: Ultimately, what I am aiming for is; Every object that follows this pattern can be translated into any other object that follows this pattern as long as there is an implementation of that translation within the "destination" object.

Comment: I may be missing something but it looks like you've modeled the inverse of that. But it sounds like it works and you're just trying to make sure that the pattern is implemented consistently. Maybe what you need is a little code generation for the boilerplate parts -- using a data file that minimally describes the classes in terms of the elements of the pattern and its variations -- sitting side-by-side with the hand-written parts.

Comment: But to answer your original question, I don't see why you couldn't write an analyzer for it but it might be more effort than it's worth. Have you considered unit tests in conjunction with test coverage analysis? (Just spitballin' there... I'm not even sure how to make that work.)